# How to highlight cells faster?

Tags: excel, vba

My spreadsheet has a column of numbers (big surprise, huh?) of which certain ones must be highlighted. This choice depends on numbers in other columns in a non-simple way, so I have a macro that goes up the list, determines whether each cell should be highlighted or un-highlighted, sets the cell as such, and loops to the next one.

This process is too slow for me. Even using `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`, and skipping cells that are already the right color, the macro takes about 10 seconds to run.

If I were changing the contents of the cells, instead of their color, I would pull the whole column into an array, run the macro on it, and paste the results back. You all know how fast that is.

But is there an equivalent method for quickly setting the highlight color of the whole column?

EDIT: Here's the code.

```
Sub HighlightCloseColumm()

Dim rVarMaxCol As Range
Dim rVarMinCol As Range
Dim rCloseCol As Range, rClose As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim rVarMax, rVarMin
Dim strEcolor As String
Dim x As Long

With ActiveSheet
    Set rVarMaxCol = .Range("VarMaxCol")
    Set rVarMinCol = .Range("VarMinCol")
    Set rCloseCol = .Range("CloseCol")
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

For i = rCloseCol.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1

    Set rVarMax = rVarMaxCol.Cells(i)
    Set rVarMin = rVarMinCol.Cells(i)
    Set rClose = rCloseCol.Cells(i)

    If rVarMax <> 0 Then
        ' Start coloring Column E red
        strEcolor = "red"
    ElseIf rVarMin <> 0 Then
        'start coloring Column E white
        strEcolor = "white"
    End If

    With rClose.Interior

        'Color it Red unless it's already red
        If strEcolor = "red" And .Pattern <> xlSolid Then
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 255
        End If

        If strEcolor = "white" And .Pattern <> xlNone Then
            'Color it White unless, you know...
            .Pattern = xlNone
        End If

        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
```

EDIT: It turns out the slowness was partly because of the unnecessary `.TintAndShade` and `.PatternTintAndShade` lines. But Tim's `BuildRange` sub is more efficient that what I was doing (and doubtless faster).

Comment: So... you want to do the same thing than the macro, but programmatically for faster results?

Comment: Yes please. I have a few ideas using a hidden helper column, but my client doesn't like those so I'm trying to avoid it.

Comment: Can you supply the code?

Comment: @Davesexcel Done.

Comment: You can read `rVarMaxCol` and `rVarMinCol` directly into arrays, instead of accessing them cell by cell, since you only need the values.  The last two settings on `rClose` always get applied, so you can do that on the whole `rCloseCol` outside of the loop.

Comment: You are using Named ranges ..Can you give the Snapshot of the named range? Isn't autofilter can be applied and then set color for the visible cell only...?

Comment: @MDIsmailHosen The color doesn't simply depend on the value of the cell. It also depends on the color of the cell below it. That's why I check each cell, one at a time, from the bottom up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should be faster: build the ranges and apply the color after the loop.

```vb
Sub HighlightCloseColumm()

    Dim arrVarMax, arrVarMin, rCloseCol As Range, rClose As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rngRed As Range, rngWhite As Range
    
    With ActiveSheet
        Set arrVarMax = .Range("VarMaxCol").Value
        Set arrVarMin = .Range("VarMinCol").Value
        Set rCloseCol = .Range("CloseCol")
    End With
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrVarMax, 1)
        Set rClose = rCloseCol.Cells(i)
        If arrVarMax(i, 1) <> 0 Then
            BuildRange rngRed, rClose
        ElseIf arrVarMin(i, 1) <> 0 Then
            BuildRange rngWhite, rClose
        End If
    Next i
    
    'anything to color?
    If Not rngRed Is Nothing Then rngRed.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If Not rngWhite Is Nothing Then rngWhite.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

End Sub

'add a range to another range
Sub BuildRange(rng As Range, rngAdd As Range)
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        Set rng = rngAdd
    Else
        Set rng = Application.Union(rng, rngAdd)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think your middle section isn't quite right -- my fault because I didn't explicitly handle the case where `rVarMax` and `rVarMin` are both 0. But that doesn't matter -- I can use your `BuildRange`  sub. Thanks!